# SVG 'tspan' element and content not matching

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm having trouble getting a `.on("click")` event to work, probably because the displayed text of an element I'm trying to click seems to mismatch its actual DOM element.

The picture illustrates the issue: when my mouse is on the `.sublabel2` element (in the example, simply the string `[]`), using Chrome's dev tool, the DOM element is highlighted in another position (blue rectangle upper left).
Any ideas what could be causing this?

[image]

The code below is what I am using. Here is how I create the main `svg:text` node:

```
pc.createAxes = function() {
  if (g) pc.removeAxes();

  // Add a group element for each dimension.
  g = pc.svg.selectAll(".dimension")
      .data(pc.getOrderedDimensionKeys(), function(d) {
        return d;
      })
    .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "dimension")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + xscale(d) + ")";
      });

 // Add an axis and title.
  myLabelNode = g.append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
      .each(function(d) {
        var axisElement = d3.select(this).call( pc.applyAxisConfig(axis, __.dimensions[d]) );

        axisElement.selectAll("path")
            .style("fill", "none")
            .style("stroke", "#222")
            .style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");

        axisElement.selectAll("line")
            .style("fill", "none")
            .style("stroke", "#222")
            .style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");
      })
    .append('svg:text') //create a node to append tspans

    setLabels(myLabelNode); 
//I skip more less relevant code here for brevity
}
```

And how I position the labels/sublabels in a separate `setLabels()` function:

```
function setLabels(svg_text_node)  {
 svg_text_node.append('tspan') 
          .attr({
                "text-anchor": "middle",
                "y": -40,
                "x": 0,
                "dy": 0,
                "class": "label"
          })

        .on("dblclick", flipAxisAndUpdatePCP)
        .on("wheel", rotateLabels)

    svg_text_node.append('tspan') 
        .attr({
            "text-anchor": "middle",
            "x": 0,
            "dy": 17,
            "class": "sublabel1"
      })


    svg_text_node.append('tspan') 
        .attr({
            "text-anchor": "middle",
            "x": 0,
            "dy": 14,
            "class": "sublabel2"
      })
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is showing the highlight in the location that the object would be in had you not repositioned it using your either absolute or relative positioning. The reason the click handler is not working is likely a z-index issue. Try giving the div a z-index higher than the rest of the items on the page and see if your click handler starts working properly.

Whenever you reposition something using absolute or relative positioning, you always need to consider how this will impact z-index and adjust for it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, so you're saying the mismatch between the highlight and the actual object shouldn't be an issue for the `on.click` event? If you have a moment, I'd be interested in knowing what to do to avoid the mismatch altogether in the function above. Is appending the `tspan`'s to an existing node not enough to set its position at the same place as the node? Otherwise, I tried setting a high z-index value (1000) and it still doesn't work properly. I fear the error is elsewhere, so I may return when I understand better what's happening.

Comment: Correct. That blue highlight is the console displaying the original position of the object. Console just works like that - but it should not impact your click event so long as the button at its reposition is not covered by another element.

Remember also that if your other parent elements do not have a z-index assigned, then the z-index on the child will not stack properly. Giving the parent position:relative, and a z-index lower than the child should fix your issue.

Comment: This is not correct. In SVG there is neither a z-index nor a position:relative!

Comment: The documenation you are referring to is SVG 2, which still is in draft status. Most SVG content around will be v1.1 instead. The first sentence from your link says *"This feature is at risk.*"! Pasting the example from that specification into a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g1pun6go/) easily shows that it is not implemented by Chrome, FF nor IE. There are loads of questions around this site based on this misconception about z-index in SVGs.

Comment: So in the end, knowing that the blue highlight from the console was not an issue helped me move forward. I believe the reason the .on click was not working was due to an unrelated issue, where the selection was done before the svg's got loaded. By adding a timer, the click event finally worked. Anyway learned interesting stuff about z-index and the DOM anyway, so thanks to both!